# Extract picture from video blob recorded with VideoJS

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, video.js

I have used VideoJS to record video on my website and send it to server where it will chop up the video into different images based on frame. But now I want to reduce server load, so I'm trying to modify my code to extract images directly after the video has been recorded but I have no idea how to do that.

Here's my videojs source code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var player = videojs("myVideo", {
        controls: true,
        fluid: true,
        width:250,
        loop: false,
        controlBar: {
            volumePanel: false,
            fullscreenToggle: true
        },
        plugins: {
            record: {
                audio: false,
                video: true,
                timeSlice: 2000,
                maxLength: 1.5,
                debug: true,
                mandatory: {
                  minWidth: 1280,
                  minHeight: 720,
                },
                video: {

                },
                // dimensions of captured video frames
                frameWidth: 1280,
                frameHeight: 720
            }
        }
}, function() {
    // print version information at startup
    var msg = 'Using video.js ' + videojs.VERSION +
        ' with videojs-record ' + videojs.getPluginVersion('record') +
        ' and recordrtc ' + RecordRTC.version;
    videojs.log(msg);
});
// user completed recording and stream is available
player.on('finishRecord', function() {
    // document.getElementById("fileupload").value = player.recordedData;
    formData.delete("video-blob")
    formData.set("video-blob",player.recordedData)
    $("#video_rec").rules('remove')
    $("#video_rec-error").remove()
    $('.submit_btn').removeAttr("disabled")
});
```

Comment: So to be clear you want to create the images AS it is being recorded?

Comment: i want to create image after the video is done recording. Maybe theres something we can do in the finishRecord event...that could generate the thumbnail from the video?

Comment: Are the frames being defined somewhere, I am trying to read the VideoJS documentation for that info.

Comment: Yeah, it definitely seems that player.on() might be where we need to chop it up. Just need to figure out how it defines the frames from the plugin in the player object

Comment: Is there a way for you to `console.log(player)` see what that looks like.

Comment: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/671/how-to-record-a-video-with-audio-in-the-browser-with-javascript-webrtc this offers same as you want.

Comment: The way to extract (i.e. preferred tool to use) would be "ffmpeg'.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882356/using-multiple-thumbnail-sprites-with-video-js-thumbnails

Answer (score 0):

See documentation at https://github.com/collab-project/videojs-record#options

You can add `image: true` to your record plugin object.

Then on `finishRecord` event you can get it through `player.recordedData`.